# Activate inputfield by click and clear selectfield after leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 links they fill the selectfield with different option. If are the textlabel is active and somebody click the link selectlist1 or other it activate the selectlabel and clear the inputfield.But if switch from the selectlabel to textinput it will not clear the selectlabel after leave, so my formular send bove input and select. The selectlabel must be clear after leave. Mayby somebody can write that all in pure js without jquery. Thank

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <script>
    var selectData = {

      "sel1": {

        "100": "select100", // selectdaten
        "101": "select101",
        "102": "select102",
        "103": "select103",
        "104": "select104"

      },
      "sel2": {

        "201": "select201",
        "202": "select202",
        "203": "select203",
        "204": "select204",
        "205": "select205"

      },
      "sel3": {

        "301": "select301",
        "302": "select302",
        "303": "select303",
        "304": "select304",
        "305": "select305"


      }
    };
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(document).on('click', '.selectin', function(event) {

        var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2');
        if (radio2.checked == false) {
          radio2.checked = true;
          toggleRadio();
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        var b = $(this),
          buttonId = b.attr('id'),
          selectSet = selectData[buttonId],
          selectField = $('#selectin');
        selectField.empty();
        if (selectSet) {
          $.each(selectSet, function(k, v) {
            selectField.append($('<option>', {
              value: k,
              text: v
            }));
          });
        }
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>

  <li><a href="#" id="sel1" class="selectin">Selectlist1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="sel2" class="selectin">Selectlist2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="sel3" class="selectin">Selectlist3</a></li>
<form method="post" name="multiform" id="form8" action="" onchange="toggleRadio();">
    <label for="radio1">INPUT Text</label>
    <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="select" checked />
    <label for="radio2">SELECT from</label>
    <input id="radio2" name="select" type="radio" />
    <label id="textLabel" for="textin">Formular
                <input id="textin" type="text" placeholder="test1" />
            </label>
    <label id="selectLabel" for="selectin">Items
                <select id="selectin">
                  <option selected>Please choose from selectlist first</option>
                  
                </select>
            </label>
  </form> 
  <script>
    function toggleRadio() { // will activate when the form will change.
      var radio1 = document.getElementById('radio1'); // radio 1
      var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2'); // radio 2
      if (radio1.checked == true) { // if the first checked display input and hide select
        document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('selectin').selectedIndex = 0; // clear selected option
      } else { // because you got only 2 option you don't have to use another condition
        document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('textin').value = ''; // clear input
      }
    }
    toggleRadio(); // call the function
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** While my original code will "clear" the select field (setting it's value to `""`) if INPUT is selected, it will still probably send something with the form.

What you want to do instead is to set `selectin.disabled = true` if `radio1.checked == true` and `selectin.disabled = false` otherwise, because disabled fields are not submited.

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

Try this code.

This is what I'm doing:

- INPUT selected: Create and select an empty option.
- SELECT selected: Remove that option.

Code:

```
function toggleRadio() {
    var radio1 = document.getElementById('radio1');
    var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2');
    var selectin = document.getElementById('selectin');
    if (radio1.checked == true) {
        document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'none';
        if (selectin.options[0].value !== '') {
            let opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = '';
            opt.innerHTML = 'Nothing selected';
            selectin.insertBefore(opt, selectin.firstChild);
        }
        selectin.selectedIndex = 0;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('textin').value = '';
        if (selectin.options[0].value === '') {
            selectin.removeChild(selectin.getElementsByTagName('option')[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry , this code will not solve the problem. It still send the seletlabel with the form when inputtext is active

Comment: yes, that's exactly how it should be. can you write me that in the code. Thank You